# Sequence Table values increments although transaction is rolled back

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I needed to have gape-less sequence for some tables Id's, so I create  Sequence table,try to avoid selecting the Max with every insert, and total count will be used for other tasks

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name="ProcedureTypeIdGen", table="REF_SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName="SEQ_NAME",
valueColumnName="SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue="SEQ_PROCEDURE_TYPE", allocationSize=1, initialValue=0)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="ProcedureTypeIdGen")
@Column(name="PROCEDURE_TYPE_ID")
private Long id;
```

But sequence value always increment every time I insert a value to PROCEDURE_TYPE, although the transaction rolled back, because of an exception and no data were inserted in PROCEDURE_TYPE table!

Comment: a sequence table is used by multiple EntityManagers, hence to use its own independent Connection makes more sense rather than locking all EntityManagers until each is committed

Comment: In may case there will be one EntityManager, and and if any one added later on(any other module), this module should not use this table and no other modules should insert data to those tables, also insertion to this table should be on a very rare cases

Comment: Some JPA implementations allow control over whether it will use the same connection as an EntityManager (e.g DataNucleus JPA that I use does). Yours may not

Answer (score 0):

Is there something that keeps you away from using GenerationType.AUTO?

Comment: I'm using Oracle which does not support Auto increment